# Can I use the word "Applicator" to describe a person in the following context?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns, meaning-in-context, adjectives

Here's the context in question, please read on:

"The final proof is in the listening and John knows this. This knowledge makes him a designer in constant dynamic relationship with what he makes, rather than an **applicator** of proven scientific knowledge."

Can I use "Applicator of knowledge" to describe a person? How does it sound to native speakers? If it does not sound right, how else may I write the same sentence?

Thanks a lot,
Maryam

Comment: I would go with: *…rather than someone who applies proven scientific knowledge.*

Comment: Maybe an *applier* of proven scientific knowledge

Comment: *Practitioner*?

Comment: The word *applicator*, to me, suggests something one might use e.g. a spray, or plastic widget for applying gel to a skin rash, or inflamed haemorrhoids. .

Comment: It's syntactically correct, and semantically correct in an awkward sense, but not particularly idiomatic.  While it is correct that the *application* of scientific knowledge is something that people do, the term "applicator" is usually reserved for a person or device which, eg, paints stuff onto something.  A more appropriate term is "applier" (though that doesn't read real great either, so it's likely best to reword things a bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is both *technically no* and *aesthetically no*. Not taking into account the fact that 'applicator' refers nearly exclusively to a device rather than a person, the word itself in the given context is too awkward and clunky anyway. I suggest using another word in its place or reconstructing the clause in question as a whole. If the latter option is your preference (which might produce a better overall sentence), you could say something like the following: *"... rather than a logician concerned only with the rigid knowledge of what is. For John, the goal always lies in what could be."*